# perl6 Is there a way to do editable prompt input?

Tags: input, default, prompt, raku

In bash shell, if you hit up or down arrows, the shell will show you your previous or next command that you entered, and you can edit those commands to be new shell commands.

In perl6, if you do

```
my $name = prompt("Enter name: ");
```

it will print "Enter name: " and then ask for input; is there a way to have perl6 give you a default value and then you just edit the default to be the new value. E.g.:

```
my $name = prompt("Your name:", "John Doe");
```

and it prints

```
Your name: John Doe
```

where the John Doe part is editable, and when you hit enter, the edited string is the value of $name.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/prompt does not show how to do it.

This is useful if you have to enter many long strings each of which is just a few chars different from others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the editing part going, you could use the Linenoise module:

```
zef install Linenoise
```

(https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-linenoise)

Then, in your code, do:

```
use Linenoise;
sub prompt($p) {
    my $l = linenoise $p;
    linenoiseHistoryAdd($l);
    $l
}
```

Then you can do your loop with prompt.  Remember, basically all Perl 6 builtin functions can be overridden lexically.  Now, how to fill in the original string, that I haven't figure out just yet.  Perhaps the libreadline docs can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you very much, Elizabeth Mattijsen !!! I will check out linenoise.

Answer (score 2):

Well by default, programs are completely unaware of their terminals.
You need your program to communicate with the terminal to do things like pre-fill an input line, and it's unreasonable to expect Perl 6 to handle something like this as part of the core language.

That said, your exact case is handled by the [Readline](https://github.com/drforr/perl6-readline) library as long as you have a compatible terminal.

It doesn't look like the perl 6 Readline has pre-input hooks setup so you need to handle the callback and read loop yourself, unfortunately. Here's my rough attempt that does exactly what you want:

```perl
use v6;
use Readline;

sub prompt-prefill($question, $suggestion) {
  my $rl = Readline.new;
  my $answer;
  my sub line-handler( Str $line ) {
    rl_callback_handler_remove();
    $answer = $line;
  }

  rl_callback_handler_install( "$question ", &line-handler );

  $rl.insert-text($suggestion);
  $rl.redisplay;
  while (!$answer) {
    $rl.callback-read-char();
  }

  return $answer;
}


my $name = prompt-prefill("What's your name?", "Bob");
say "Hi $name. Go away.";
```

---

If you are still set on using [Linenoise](https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-linenoise), you might find the 'hints' feature good enough for your needs (it's used extensively by the `redis-cli` application if you want a demo). See the `hint` callback used with `linenoiseSetHintsCallback` in [the linenoise example.c file](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise). If that's not good enough you'll have to start digging into the guts of linenoise.

Comment: Thank you Timbus! I will check out Readline and your codes !!

Comment: No problem. But I should mention that I couldn't install Readline on my machine today. Turns out a very recent change broke the install but there's a workaround until it is fixed: https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/148#issuecomment-289458725

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

Use [io-prompt](https://github.com/wbiker/io-prompt)
With that you can set a default value and even a default type:

```
my $a = ask( "Life, the universe and everything?", 42, type => Num );
Life, the universe and everything? [42]
Int $a = 42
```

You can install it with:

```
zef install IO::Prompt
```

However, if just a default value is not enough. Then it is better you use the approach Liz has suggested.

Comment: Thank you Wolf and LuFFy, I will check out IO::Prompt !!